# Probability the driver has no accident in the next 365 days

Tags: probability

> The time until the next car accident for a particular driver is
> exponentially distributed with a mean of 200 days. Calculate the
> probability that the driver has no accidents in the next 365 days, but
> then has at least one accident in the 365-day period that follows this
> initial 365-day period.

### Attempt

Let $T$ be the time it takes for a driver to have a car accident. We are given $T$ is $exp( \lambda = 1/200 )$. We need to find

$$ P(T > 365) = 1 - F(365) = 1 - 1 + e^{-365/200} = 0.1612 $$

Is this correct? MY answer key says the correct answer should be $\boxed{0.1352}$. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the first accident to be between the first year and second year.

\begin{align}
P(365< T \leq 2 \cdot 365) &= F(2 \cdot 365) - F(365) 
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Indeed if you read the problem carefully you want: $$P(365 * 2 >T > 365 ) = F(365*2) - F(365)$$

Comment: This is not enough for an answer. Reading carefully is not doing maths. Maths is reasoning. So if you want to answer this question in a useful way, please explain every reasoning from the problem statement to the result.

Answer (score 1):

You want to go the next 365 days accident-free and then want to have an accident within the next 365 days (days 365-730). After day 730 you do not want any more accidents.

Day 0-365: No accidents

Day 365-730: At least 1 accident

Day 730+: No accidents

In the solution, you forgot to subtract off the probability of an accident occurring after day 730. After doing so you get

$$P(730>T>365)=F(730)−F(365)=e^{730/200}-e^{365/200}=0.13523$$